# Representing date having 32 as maximum value for Day

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am building application in asp.net using Sql server 2005. In my application I have to represent many dates & dates are of Nepali(Bikram sambhat) in which the maximum day for some month can be 32.

So what is the best option to represent the date in sql server so that 32 can be placed for day value & that can be easily compared(manipulated) in sql server as well as in asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an easy conversion from Nepali to Gregorian. Think of it in two ways:

- need to show Nepali date
- need to manipulate (e.g. find difference between months, days etc)

The first one is easy - store as a varchar
The 2nd one is not.  If you wanted to know the difference between 2 Nepali dates, you can store the date a 2nd date as the Gregorian equivalent and use datediff/dateadd(day) between them. However, dateadd(month) will be useless for you here unless you wanted to know the difference of 2 Nepali dates `in Gregorian date months` - not common.

Sounds like just storing in varchar and having a library for Nepali dates, either in the front end or as a CLR, would go down better.

---

It may help for conversions to have a fully materialized Nepali date table with the corresponding Gregorian date, so the layout would be

```
NepaliYear   NepaliMonth   NepaliDay  Gregorian
x            4             2          2014-21-23
etc
```

But I am not sure it would help much for (Nepali) date maths beyond conversion - and only if you need such conversion within SQL Server.

#### EDIT

@pst's comment

There is a reason to prefer VARCHAR to datetime.  I assumed that the frequency, most of the activity is reading/writing a Nepali date - which is stored and read as a VARCHAR - no conversion. If and only when date maths *is* required does it involve the library - in which case you invoke conversion, and only then if you need at any point in time the Gregorian calendar equivalent. If all you wanted is maths between NepaliDate/scalar or NepaliDate/NepaliDate - again, datetime offers no benefit whatsoever - **it cannot handle day #32 in a month**.

Comment: I see no reason to use a varchar/varbinary/decimal field over a datetime field -- especially if both are 'handled via a library'. It just makes it more difficult to deal with in the DB and removes validation. (I was also sort of expecting this response to include a reference to a user-defined .NET type).

Comment: @pst - see edited answer. It's a long response so I included it in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is a guy that has implemented some classes for converting between Nepali dates and Gregorian dates. This way you can input dates in the Nepali format but store them in a format that SQL Server understands. Look here: http://rrajbhandari.blogspot.com/2010/06/bikram-sambat-classes-and-controls.html

Remember that a date in either calendar can be converted to another calendar - they point to the same day.

Comment: Currently I am doing that way, but directly representing nepali date having 32 in day field with DateTime type of sql server is not valid, so I am representing as varchar & I could not compare them directly

Comment: @ramkumar: I wouldn't store the date as a varchar. Instead I would store it as a regular sql date and do a conversion when displaying the date. The same conversion would have to be done when inputting dates from the user. This would allow you to use the regular sql server date functions to do comparisons and all that stuff, so it would probably simplify your code.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the built in Date type. It sounds like any date in your format can be easily converted into the standard sql format.

I would just write a utility to convert any date from sql server into your display format whenever you load or write to the database.

Comment: can Date type support 32/12/2012 ?

Comment: Or if most of the time it is just stored and retrieved, why go through conversion from/to SQL Server datetime (Gregorian based) at all?

Comment: Because SQL server is built to handle Gregorian dates, not Nepali dates. It is better to use built in datatypes than to hack your own types in and lose all of the built in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Nepali calendar](http://www.ashesh.com.np/nepali-calendar/), it may help.

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.